# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd7: Invalid continuation byte

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

NOTE: This testing is being run as part of the target sites bug bounty program.

I am trying to parse results returned from Google using `requests` in `Python3`.

The issue I am having is that I am getting the below error:

`'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 5698: invalid continuation byte`

This is the relevant code:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.soup = BeautifulSoup(features="html.parser")
    self.query_addr = "http://www.google.com/search?"

def parse_search_results(self, res):
    links = []
    soup = self.soup(res) # This call triggers the error
    no_results = soup.find("did not match any documents.")
```

Screenshot:

I saved the result of `res` (which is a bytes object) in an html file and viewed it in the browser. You can see the offending bytes rendered.

[image]

This is the value of `res` without the enclosing `b''`, I've put it up on [Github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/richardcurteis/downloads/master/test.html).

I am also not explicitly calling `decode` anywhere in my code or specifiying `utf-8`. My understanding is that `BeautifulSoup` handles that itself.

What do I need to do in order for `BeautifulSoup` to parse this data correctly?

Comment: Once you take a look here, you will understand that behavior https://blog.furas.pl/python-why-requests-incorrectly-decodes-text-instead-of-utf8-gb.html